# Responsive design - percentages and pixels and ems

Tags: css, frontend, responsive-design

I'm starting off building a site which should be responsive to different screen sizes. I'm using the Fluid Baseline Grid template which uses percentages for columns and adjusts according to screen sizes using media queries. Now that I'm adding my own custom CSS, I am wondering whether I should be using pixels, percentages or ems for positioning my elements (within the fluid grid elements). For example, margins and padding between divs, widths of input fields etc. Font sizes and line heights are the only things set to use ems for measurement.

Can anyone provide any pointers on this? At the moment I'm leaning towards just using pixels within the percentage based layout that the grid template has preset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you should be using percentages whenever possible, at least on the horizontal plane, so the margins and padding can expand/contract *proportionally* with the rest of the content. A `10px` margin might be great at small resolutions, but it could look much too tight at much larger ones.

Comment: Thanks Nate, that makes sense. I've just been looking at some sites which have been built to be responsive and for element widths, margin and padding, there seems to be a mix of pixels and percentages used throughout, which is slightly confusing - e.g margin: 30px 1% 0 0. Any rationale for this approach?

Comment: Well, in the case of `margin: 30px 1% 0 0` the `30px` is being applied to the top margin, not the left or right. Without seeing the design, I would assume this is an aesthetic decision to maintain a consistent visual flow. "Responsiveness" is less of an issue on the vertical, since scrolling in that direction is universally accepted.